# OpenDNS blocks requests sent to VPN Server

Tags: linux, openvpn, opendns

Full disclosure: I am using a VPN to circumvent security measure set in place by my netadmin to torrent music.

Recently, my dad installed the OpenDNS system in our home to prevent users from accessing inappropriate, illegal, and malicious websites. I purchased one year of access from Privateinternetaccess.com and got it installed on my pc and my phone. I had wanted to set up an ArchLinux machine I had lying around as a seedbox using this VPN, but after following the instructions at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Private_Internet_Access_VPN I was still not able to bypass security, as I had on my android phone and windows PC.

I had first considered it to be a problem with NetworkManager, so I tried connman, then when that failed, I used openvpn to connect manually. However, upon trying to do so, I noticed in the openvpn verbose log that my vpn client had failed to ascertain the IP address of the remote server, finding instead the openDNS "Blocked" page.

Today, I tried a secondary workaround by pinging the target host from a computer with unfettered access, and modifying the openvpn configuration files to use the ip address rather than the proper name of the remote server. The log shows

> sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/US_East.conf
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:49 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.13 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)]
>
> [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Nov  3 2016
>   Sun Nov 27 16:39:49 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016, LZO 2.09
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:49 2016 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow 
>   this configuration to call user-defined scripts
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:49 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:49 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]208.167.254.96:1198
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:50 2016 [eda89b4680481f08ebe2274bb298496d] Peer Connection 
>   Initiated with [AF_INET]208.167.254.96:1198
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:52 2016 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:52 2016 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:52 2016 /usr/bin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:52 2016 /usr/bin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.19.10.6 peer 
>   10.19.10.5
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:52 2016 /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf.sh tun0 1500 1558
>
> 10.19.10.6 10.19.10.5 init
>
> dhcp-option DNS 209.222.18.222
>
> dhcp-option DNS 209.222.18.218
>
> Sun Nov 27 16:39:52 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed

The address of BLOCKED is `204.194.237.154`
the address of the target server us-east.privateinternetaccess.com = `216.155.131.75`

The next strategy I will try is to use L2TP/IPSEC using openswan, but i fear that it will go badly. I feel that no tool from linux may reach the target server, as when I was attempting to use the socks proxy provided by PIA to download the software itself, the proxy tool failed.

TL;DR VPN can't connect to remote server through OpenDNS. What do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about circumventing network security/policies set by your network administrator.

Comment: “I am using a VPN to circumvent security measure [...] to torrent music.” – Yeah, how about no? Really, what year is this. Torrenting illegal content *will* get you into legal trouble.

Comment: Would you have answered if I made up some excuse that sounds like an almost reasonable reason to bypass openDNS? Could have said I'm getting the latest debian bootstrap image, or that in order to play a local co-op videogame with a friend, I need to use a VPN to connect to his NATed subnet; or something like that. I respect that you're blocking me on this, but I just wanted to be honest. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to configure around the DNS. I set my resolv.conf to PIA's DNS, which resolved the program and allowed me to use NM to handle VPN connections.